# Using chart.js version 3, How do create Custom Labels with Links?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.jsv3

I'm using Charts JS and I'd like to create some custom Labels on a Stacked Bar Chart. I'm trying to recreate this following chart:
[image]

How do I create custom labels as circled in Red above? I'd like to link to other pages with these labels. Actually the bolded text would link to one page and the normal text would link to another page.

Also How would you label each bar in a way that the values drop down off the bar when there is not enough room to display it on the bar? See the "4%" or "6%" on the right side of the graph.

I also want to know how to put a margin spacing between each stacked bar. See the vertical white space between each bar on the image above.

Any help with the issues above would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest, there is so much special you need in your chart, that I would not use chart.js but create my own chart. It’s not that complicated to create once all the components for a row and then repeat the creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own chart using div and widths. Sometime you have more control over look and feel if you build it your self.